# Tem como transformar uma string literal em uma variavel?

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Procurei na web, mas não vi como transformar uma string simples em uma variavel, vi o parse_str mas não é bem o que preciso.
Quero o seguinte, tenho a string "nomeusuario1", e gostaria que ela fosse transformada em "$nomeusuario1".

Suponha que tenho um Row["nomecampo"] e ele passa por uma

```
foreach ($Row as $key => $value), 
quero transformar os nomes dos campos em variaveis, 
ou seja $."key" = $novovalor
```

Mas não aceita.
Preciso disso porque as strings vem de um foreach e não sei exatamente o conteudo, só sei que não é um conteudo que pode dar erro na construção da variavel, pois sao nomes de campos.

Comment: Por que vc não faz : `$nomeusuario1 = "sua string";` ?

Comment: Tem, mas normalmente não precisa fazer isto, em praticamente todos casos é gambiarra, inseguro e o programador vai se dar mal com isso. E acho que já foi respondido antes. Preciso achar.

Comment: Porque nomeusuario1 é um exemplo, ela nao existe, as variaveis serão criadas a partir de strings que não sei quais são.

Comment: Dependendo das respostas vou analisar se é viavel usar a sugestao ou partir pra outra coisa

Comment: Bom se vc detalhar um pouco mais a forma como recebe esses dados... fica melhor

Comment: @MagicHat, suponha que tenho um Row["nomecampo"] e ele passa por uma foreach ($Row as $key => $value), quero transformar os nomes dos campos em variaveis, ou seja $."key" = $novovalor

Comment: Coloca esse código aí , que fica mais fácil,,,

Comment: Esse é um caso pra usar *array* associativo mesmo, conforme é falado na duplicata.